# NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 Support for Netbeans IDE 7

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I am starting a computer science class and need to download Netbeans IDE on my Mac 10.6.8. The latest Netbeans edition compatible with my Mac is NetBeans 7. However, in my class, we use NetBeans IDE 8.0.2

Am I able to transfer projects between both versions (via thumb drive) and edit them on both versions of Netbeans?

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it, but I have had trouble in the past with some custom Ant extensions Netbeans uses breaking when you try to use an older version of Netbeans than the one the project was created with. The other way seems to be less problematic.  I have almost always been able to open projects created with an older version of Netbeans with a newer one.

I think there are two options:

1. Copy the sources but just create a new project with the older Netbeans using existing sources as needed. If you haven't customized a lot of settings this is usually fine.
2. Use Maven projects instead of Ant projects (which are just called Java applications in the Netbeans projects window). Just select Maven in the categories list in the new project dialog.  These projects are less closely tied to the Netbeans versions, they can even be imported fairly reliably into Eclipse and Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

copy the source folder(netbeansprojects[Your project]\src) and copy it to a thumb drive. Open a new project in your pc (the one in your class, 8.0.2) and go to THAT projects src, delete it, and replace it with the one from you're flash drive.